# How to query documents of last group occurrence in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, time-series, grouping

### Context from a developer perspective

Documents in my Mongo collection belongs to groups if they share two fields (let's call them 'group' and 'subgroup') and they are consecutive (the groups are actually a time-series). Note that there are many realizations of the same 'group' and 'subgroup' combination and they are distinct groups because they don't belong to the same time-series.

**Is it possible to query the last time-series, that is to say all documents (descending on timestamp) till 'group' or 'subgroup' changes value the first time?**

### Real Context

This was the abstracted context; maybe it could be useful to reformulate the context in its real fashion. The documents in my collection are sensor measures and 'group' and 'subgroup' identifies the type of production process. Each production process is repeated many times but never consecutively.

I need to query the measures of the last production process.

### My current solution

I know that the maximum duration of a time-series (production process) is *n* seconds so I queried the last *n* seconds with python and got the last occurrence of 'group' + 'subgroup' using pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're not talking about super scale your approach seems fine, however if you can have many many documents in the last `n` seconds I recommend letting the database do the heavy lifting.

Here is a code sample for the `nodejs` driver:

```
const nSecondsAgo = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000 * n);

// get last document in db
const lastDocument = await db.collection.findOne({
timestamp: {$gt: nSecondsAgo}}, { sort: { timestamp: -1 } });

// get last document in db from a different group/subgroup.
const lastOtherGroupDocument = await db.collection.findOne({
    $or: [
        {group: {$ne: lastDocument.group}},
        {subgroup: {$ne: lastDocument.subgroup}}
    ],
    timestamp: { $gt: nSecondsAgo }
}, {sort: {timestamp: -1}});

// if no "other" document just use last N seconds as your start reference.
const seriesStartTime = lastOtherGroupDocument?.timestamp ?? nSecondsAgo;

//fetch results
const seriesData = await db.collection.find({timestamp: {$gt: seriesStartTime $lte: lastDocument.timestamp})

// or if it's possible data is still coming in:
const seriesData = await db.collection.find({
        timestamp: {$gt: seriesStartTime},
        group: lastOtherGroupDocument.group,
        subgroup: lastOtherGroupDocument.subgroup
    },
)
```

If you build a decending index on `timestamp` and a complex index on `group, subgroup, timestamp` all these queries will be supported by it. and the query time should be somewhat instant.

I will say this again, if you're not loading in tens of thousands of documents from the last `n` seconds your current approach is fine. Only when the scale gets too large or you start experiencing performance issue's I recommend you switch.